# khtml library tutorials/guides?

Tags: c++, kde-plasma, kdelibs

I'm trying to use the khtml library, basically just the DOM html implementation from there, but I even failed to create a basic `HTMLDocument` from a file using `load()`, and when I tried to create a `HTMLDOcument` by mutating it via `appendChild` I get `DOMException` with `errorcode == 8 (NOT FOUND)`.

Can anyone please point me to some sample code which uses khtml's dom model without obtaining the document from the GUI components?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see what the problem was.

First, if you're using a local html file, your uri needs to be absolute when you call DOM::HTMLDocumemt::load(const DOM::DOMString&).

Secondly, you need to create a DOM document, but it's read-only by default after creation.
So, before you actually call load(), you need to make it editable via

DOM::Document::setDesignMode(bool designOn).

That fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

If I may recommend, WebKit is far superior to khtml now, even konqueror will be using webkit by default next release.

Check [QtWebkit](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtwebkit.html).

Comment: As far as I know QtWebKit requires you to run X11. For a server that's not a good option.

Comment: @AlexisWilke it doesn't require you to run X11, the widget part of it requires being linked against x11. It works fine without X running.